# Как получить элемент Xml C#

Tags: c#

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project name="Arma3">
  <Package name="Main">
    <Key ID="STRCAMP_03bv01">
      <Original>&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;Men, this evening you can put your feet up and relax. You've earned it. &lt;br/&gt;I'm going back to Le Moule. You're in charge.&lt;/t&gt;</Original>
      <English>&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;Men, this evening you can put your feet up and relax. You've earned it. &lt;br/&gt;I'm going back to Le Moule. You're in charge.&lt;/t&gt;</English>
      <Chinese>&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;今晚大家可以翘起脚来好好休息一下了，这是你们应得的。&lt;br/&gt;现在我要回到Le Moule，这里由你来指挥。&lt;/t&gt;</Chinese>
      <Chinesesimp>&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;今晚大家可以翘起脚来好好休息一下了，这是你们应得的。&lt;br/&gt;现在我要回到Le Moule，这里由你来指挥。&lt;/t&gt;</Chinesesimp>
    </Key>
    <Key ID="STRCAMP_03bv02">
      <Original>&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;Hmm. Something tells me we won't be doing much relaxing this evening.&lt;/t&gt;</Original>
      <English>&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;Hmm. Something tells me we won't be doing much relaxing this evening.&lt;/t&gt;</English>
      <Chinese>&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;唔，我有预感我们今天晚上不会太轻松。&lt;/t&gt;</Chinese>
      <Chinesesimp>&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;唔，我有预感我们今天晚上不会太轻松。&lt;/t&gt;</Chinesesimp>
    </Key>
  </Package>
</Project>
```

```
public static void SetText(string Id, string TranslateText)
    {
        XElement root = XElement.Load("Test.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> code =
            from el in root.Elements("Key")
            where (string)el.Attribute("ID") == Id
            select el;
        foreach (XElement el in code)//Element.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (el.Name == "Original")
            {
                OriginalText = el.Value;
                if (OriginalText.IndexOf("&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;") > -1)
                {
                    el.Add(new XElement("Russian", "&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;" + TranslateText + "&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;"));
                }
                else
                {
                    el.Add(new XElement("Russian",TranslateText));
                }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Мне нужно получить к примеру Key ID="STRCAMP_03bv01" (Это переменная ID, передаётся именно STRCAMP_03bv01). После этого нужно добавить в него Russian Тут мой текст /Russian но он не находит STRCAMP....

Решение проблемы (спасибо за наводку tym32167):

```
        public static void SetText(string Id, XElement root, string TranslateText)
    {         
        IEnumerable<XElement> code =
            from el in root.Descendants("Key")
            where (string)el.Attribute("ID") == Id
            select el;
        foreach (XElement el in code)//Element.ChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (var d in el.Descendants())
            {
                if (d.Name == "Original")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(d);
                    OriginalText = d.ToString();
                    if (OriginalText.IndexOf("&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;") > -1)
                    {
                        el.Add(new XElement("Russian", @"&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;" + TranslateText + @"&lt;t size='0.6'&gt;"));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        el.Add(new XElement("Russian", TranslateText));
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: XML, что вы показали, невалиден. Код, что вы показали, не компилируется.

Comment: Ну у меня всё нормально, проблема на вашей стороне, и я дал отрывки, не вижу смысла давать весь код

Comment: какие стороны, у вас теги в XML не закрыты и скобок не хватает в коде.

Comment: Я конечно всё понимаю но можно и додуматься что в конце </Key>
  </Package>
</Project>

Comment: вы же хотите, чтобы вам помогли решить проблему? Но зачем это кому то делать, если вы так небрежны в оформлении вопроса? То есть если кто то захочет вам помочь, то вместо простой копипасты вашего текста он должен за вас что то дописывать?

Comment: Меня интересует конкретный вопрос, и я выложил всё что нужно, копипастить мой код необязательно, знающий человек  просто посмотрит на IEnumerable<XElement> code =.... и возможно поможет, либо поможет переделать

Comment: Да без проблем, ваше право оформлять вопрос как вам нравится. Я бы вам уже ответ написал, но я потратил уже своё время на нашу беседу и уже не могу написать вам ответ сегодня. Но я всё же надеюсь, что вы последуете моей просьбе, оформите свой вопрос как следует, а с меня вам мой недописанный ответ https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFkuN.png .

Comment: Пишите ответ ответом, ответу в вопросе делать нечего. Ну и видел сегодня [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57772340/312041), может вм будет интересно почитать.